# How to use nested for loops to return string "1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+.."?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to define a receieved a string in int form that results in list form of the addition of numbers leading to the given string
eg when `n = 3` the returned string should be:

```
"1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+.."
```

My attempt:

```
def nestedAdditions(n):
    string = ""
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
         for j in range(1,i+1): 
             string += str(j)+"+" 
    string += ".."
    return(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use another method, but with minimum changes to your code, here you are:

```
def nestedAdditions(n):

    string = ""

    for i in range(1,n+1): 

         # change to n
         for j in range(1,n+1): 

             string += str(j)+"+" 

         # fix loop indentation
         string += ".."

    return(string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly counting from `1` to `i+1` in the inner loop while you should use `n+1`. You are also incorrectly appending the `..` after the outer loop terminates. Try this:

```
def nestedAdditions(n):
    string = ""
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
         for j in range(1,n+1): 
             string += str(j)+"+" 
         string += ".."
    return(string)
```

then

```
print(nestedAdditions(3))
```

should print

```
1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+..
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an itertools approach:

```
import itertools as it
def iterAdditions(n):
    item = list(it.accumulate([str(x) + '+' for x in range (1, n+1)]))
    temp = item.pop() + '..'
    return (temp * n)
```

gives for `iterAdditions(3)`:

```
'1+2+3+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+..'
```

It does speed things up a little bit above the basic nested for loop approach (@ Selcuk & Anatoliy above), although I'm not entirely sure why:

```
timeit nestedAdditions(10)
20.2 µs ± 166 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

timeit iterAddition(10)
2.74 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I did some tests and it seems like `''.join` is asymptotically faster than `itertools.accumulate` if you want to add a lot of strings together, though. That makes sense because `accumulate` has to yield all the intermediate results of the additions, so the total length of all yielded strings is O(N^2) when joining N strings. Your solution probably beats the naive nested loop because of the string multiplication at the end.

Answer (score 1):

No nested loops needed for this; use `'+'.join` to make the string with one repetition, and multiply the string by `n` to repeat it. Yes, you can multiply a string by a number in Python.

```py
def rep(n):
    parts = [ str(i) for i in range(1, n+1) ]
    parts.append('..')
    s = '+'.join(parts)
    return s * n
```

@neutrino_logic posted running times, so for comparison:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: rep(100), number=100000)
1.6885969130016747
>>> timeit(lambda: iterAdditions(100), number=100000)
2.435769292002078
```